JSF Netbeans Framework not working
In the Projects window (Ctrl-1; ⌘-1 on Mac), right-click your project node and choose Properties to open the Project Properties window. Select the Frameworks category and then click the Add button. Select JavaServer Faces in the Add a Framework dialog box. Click OK.
I have tried the above, but the ok button is greyed out and I cannot continue.
Any help appreciated.
Nigel
ubuntu 24, Netbeans 22, JDK 21.
